# double summation of conditional variable depending on sum of integer

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I am having trouble with taking a certain summation and finding an explicit value for the summation. The summation is:
$$
S = \sum_{w=3}^a \lambda_w \sum_{m=w}^a \lambda_m
$$
The only information available is
\begin{align*}
k = \sum_{v=1}^a \lambda_v
\end{align*}
Where $k$ is a positive integer. I am looking to find out if this has an generalized explicit value of this summation. I would also like to learn how i can do these types of problems in the future. Suggested tags are welcome.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

I know that
$$
\sum_{m=w}^a \lambda_m = k-\sum_{m=1}^{w-1} \lambda_m
$$
Yet once this is played out i end up with:
\begin{align*}
S = \sum_{w=3}^a \lambda_w (k-\sum_{m=1}^{w-1}\lambda_m) \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad
\\
= (k-\lambda_1 -\lambda_2 - \lambda_3)(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3) - \sum_{w=4}^a \lambda_w\sum_{m=4}^{w-1} \lambda_m\qquad
\end{align*}
Which leaves me nowhere.

Comment: Maybe write things out for a few smallish values of $a$?

Comment: I believe there's a mistake in the before last line, the $k$ alone shouldn't be in the sum

Comment: @GeorgSaliba I believe i fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_{w=3}^a \lambda_w (k-\sum_{m=1}^w\lambda_m) \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad
\\
&= k^2-k(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)-\sum_{w=3}^a \sum_{m=1}^w\lambda_m\lambda_w\\
&=k^2-k(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)-\sum_{m=3}^a\sum_{w=m}^a \lambda_m\lambda_w -\lambda_1 k-\lambda_2k+(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2
\end{align*}
You might recognize the double sum as $S$ itself. Hence

$$2S=k^2-2k(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)+(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)^2$$
$$2S=(k-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2))^2$$

P.S.: I don't know if the value $(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$ is allowed to figure in the "generalized explicit value".

Comment: Brilliant answer, I knew it was some sort of polynomial but I can't believe i didn't see it that way. Yes the $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are good. I made a typo in the original question, but I worked it out with your answer.

Comment: @EricLawson glad to be of some help